# g++ compiler: error invalid conversion from 'pthread_t {aka long unsigned int}' to 'void* (*)(void*)' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, compilation, pthreads

I'm trying to compile my program on the command line and I got this error. It was pointing to the pthread_create line in the following code. I have the correct import for pthreads and I am running on Ubuntu so I know that's not the problem. Otherwise, I'm clueless about what's going on.

```
int main() {
    pthread_t thinker;
    if(pthread_create(&thinker, NULL, thinker, NULL)) {
         perror("ERROR creating thread.");
    }
    pthread_join(thinker, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly should your thread do when it's started?

Comment: Why use the pthreads API? It's 2015. We have had `std::thread` for ages, and `boost::thread` for AGES before that.

Comment: `void*(*)(void*)` is a pointer to a function while you are trying to pass an integer value

Comment: _"Otherwise, I'm clueless about what's going on."_ Yeah so are we. You forgot to tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry everyone. This is for a school project and pthreads were barely explained and we are required to use them, it's not a choice :( the thinker method breaks down a string input and validates it. Afterwards there are other threads inside it that does other things with that input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of thread creation is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t * thread, 
                       const pthread_attr_t * attr,
                       void * (*start_routine)(void *), 
                       void *arg);
```

If you see in your code, you are passing `thinker` as 3rd param which is not compatible with `void * (*start_routine)(void *)`. It should be function pointer. It should be:

```
void *callback_function( void *ptr ){}

pthread_create(&thinker, NULL, callback_function, NULL)
```

Comment: I actually have thinker as a void* function like that. It's called like so: void* thinker (void* parm) { } ... but I think I just realized that my problem is that my pthread and my method have the same name.... I'll try changing one of them and see if it works.

Comment: ... that was the problem. Thanks for pointing out the error. Should I delete this post since it was a little error that doesn't really have to do with pthreads or anything in particular?

Comment: @user2872777 if someone will do the same mistake this will be helpful. Just mark this as correct.